# PyAudio differentiating between audio streams

Tags: python, raspbian

I’ve been struggling to get two projects to work nicely together and have surmised that one of them needs an alteration to work properly.

I’m running a Pi3B with the latest Buster OS. Attached to the Pi is an IQaudIO DAC+ [linky](http://iqaudio.co.uk/hats/8-pi-dac.html) and a USB mic.

The pi runs [Shairport-Sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync) to receive audio from iOS devices over airplay and outputs via the IQaudIO HAT, with excellent quality I should add!

I wanted to add visualisation so attached LEDs will respond to the music and found the following git that runs on Pi [audio-reactive-leds](https://github.com/scottlawsonbc/audio-reactive-led-strip)

The audio-reactive-led software uses PyAudio and as best as I can tell commandeers the default audio device.

If the audio-reactive-led software is run, and the USB mic left to observe any peripheral audio then it works perfectly.

But when Shairport-sync is outputting audio, and the visualisation is run the audio output is dropped. Previously I’d used a USB speaker/mic sound card and swapping the speakers from the IQaudIO HAT to the USB speaker put resulted in the audio playing again (although crappy quality).

So, my question, can the python script of the audio-reactive-LEDs software be altered to observe only the microphone input whilst leaving the audio outputting to the IQaudIO device.

Note, I have altered the Shairport-sync configuration so it will always output to IQaudIO (rather than ‘default’, which was the previous setting).

Thanks very much